# How to enable/disable editing a specific column in a Vaadin Grid?

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a Vaadin Grid (myGrid) where I have enabled cell editing using

```
myGrid.setEditorEnabled(true);
```

However, I would like to disallow editing the cells in one particular column. How can I do this? The only workaround I can think of is to intercept the call to the model bean and throw some exception / show a message to the user. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

`myGrid.setEditorEnabled(true);`

does not automatically make every cell editable. You need to specify a `Binder` for every editable column. As stated in [Vaadin docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html#components.grid.editing):

> The editor is based on Binder which is used to bind the data to the
>   editor. (...) For each column that should be editable, a binding should
>   be created in the editor binder and then the column is configured to
>   use that binding.

So if you want to disallow editing in a specific column, then just don't provide a binder for it.

Comment: I am using Vaadin 7. I think the Binder is a Vaadin 8 feature. However, it looks like I could use the editor field in Vaadin 7...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my solution

```
indexedContainer = new IndexedContainer();
indexedContainer.addContainerProperty("name",String.class,"");
//....
//in add item process do the following 
Item item = indexedContainer.getItem(indexedContainer.addItem());
item.getItemProperty("name").setValue(myModel.getName());
item.getItemProperty("name").setReadOnly(true);
//...
myGrid.setContainerDataSource(container);
```

that's it

I think there is another way but I did not test it

```
myGrid.getColumn("name").setEditable(false)
```

hope this helps you